# Listing users with boolean set to true in DB PHP

Tags: php, boolean

I'm working on a basic chat application, keep in mind the idea is extremely simple. I wanted to set a boolean in the database to true every time the user logged in and false every time the user logged out, to verify whether the user is online/offline. How would I go about returning a list of users where only the users with the boolean set to true are returned?

Comment: Are you asking what the SQL query would look like, or what the PHP script would look like?

Comment: Simply use sessions instead of DB for chech user online/ofline

Comment: MySQL doesn't have boolean fields.  Most ofter people use tinyint fields with a value of 1 or 0 in it. Outside of that it is jsut like any other database query.

Comment: @Winston He wants a list of all users that are online not an indicating of whether a single user is online.

Comment: There is no *real* way to track if users are online/offline like this with PHP because unless the user explicitly logs out the flag in the database will never be cleared. The best solution is to keep track of the time of the user's last *activity* and assume that all users active within the last X minutes are "online".

Comment: Yes, I meant tinyint.

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE flag=1";
```

Then pass this string to your database and get the results.